# Make javah ignore inner classes when generating JNI headers?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, javah

Exactly what the title says.

I have a class which declares certain `native` methods, but also has a couple of inner classes. The `javah` utility insists on generating separate headers for the inner classes *even though they don't have any `native` method declarations*. Is there a way to force `javah` to stop doing this (annotations, secret command-line switches, anything)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know any way to do that. (I use the Oracle JDK.)

I understand the annoyance but the problem is limited to unnecessary files and their unnecessary regeneration (outer class changes result in rewriting the useless header files for inner classes).

To solve the problem, I just delete all the empty header files. I use Ant, since it is available as a generic project builder step in Eclipse.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="javah">
    <mkdir dir="javah" />

    <javah classpath="bin" destdir="javah">
        <!-- list classes here -->
        <class name="com.example.Outer" />
        <class name="com.example.OuterWithNatives" />
    </javah>

    <delete>
        <fileset dir="javah">
            <not>
                <contains text="JNIEXPORT" />
            </not>
        </fileset>
    </delete>

</project>
```

Comment: Good solution -- automatically deleting them is fine with me!